# setting up database for sortable tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

probably a bit of a noob question...I got partway to solving it on my own but...

I'm making a basis application that has a database of legal decisions, which will be represented in a table that would preferably have sortable columns whereever that's possible. For example, I wish to be able to sort them by date.

I'll be using class methods for this

```
  def self.judgementdate
    order("judgementdate DESC")
  end
```

Questions: 
Should I create the column as a string or an integer? How should I enter the date into the database to make it most easily sortable. for example, should I enter January 27, 2012 as

```
27/01/2012

or

"January 27, 2012"
```

or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`date` column](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types) to store dates, not `string` nor `integer`, `date`. Then the database will sort them just fine and even know how to manipulate them as dates; if you use some other type then you'll end up doing bizarre string mangling or a bunch of pointless (and probably incorrect in edge cases) arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, after I posted the question, I realized I should just check the automatically generated created_at columns for the proper date format. so I'm entering date like this. Rails sorts it fine!

```
2012-07-26
```